# str_to_date driving me nuts in mysql

Tags: mysql, date

```
UPDATE `smart_userstest`
SET lastlogin = STR_TO_DATE(lastlogin,'%d/%m/%y %h:%i')
WHERE lastlogin REGEXP('^[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4}$')
```

Have a query that I have used before... Except now I am getting errors.

So I have imported excel spreadsheets hitting my DB.  Lots of date fields.  Most are in a new format which I am trying to fix.  m/d/yyyy hour:min where month, day, hour, and min can be 1-2 numbers.  I would like to simply get rid of the hour:min portion and set the date to a proper MySql DATE.  Also I would like it to account for the hour:min portion being left blank because I have both.

Example error:
1411 - Incorrect datetime value: '1/24/2014' for function str_to_date

Comment: `STR_TO_DATE(lastlogin,'%d/%m/%y')`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat - Then I get " 1411 - Incorrect datetime value: '9/24/2013 14:32' for function str_to_date" - that was first thing I tried.

Comment: Ah, I see.  You have both and need to parse both.

Comment: Why are you storing the last login as a string and not a DATETIME in the first place?

Comment: @kba - I am only storing it in the sense that it is what is imported.  The purpose of the question is that I do not want to store it as a string and want to set it to a DATE (time is irrelevant).  If I have the field set a DATE then the "users" files will fail if the format isn't exactly right - so they would probably spend 20 years updating their stuff.

Comment: What "users files" will fail? You should always store it as a DATE or DATETIME and convert it to the appropriate format either during selection or later in your application.

Comment: @kba - It isn't an app. They load a file into a folder - via web app.  Based on the name a batch job is done to import the data.  Gets put in helper table then over to regular table after stuff like this happens.  Open to suggestions if there is a better way to do things.  But know I have like 40 different reports with each their own issue coming in so letting the app side do it IMO would be a mess.  I was actually searching for a good excel import app and found really nothing.

Comment: I'm guessing you have a script that does the import. Do the conversion there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this with a `case`:

```
UPDATE `smart_userstest`
    SET lastlogin = (case when lastlogin like '%/%/% %:%' then STR_TO_DATE(lastlogin,'%d/%m/%y %h:%i')
                          when lastlogin like '%/%/%' then STR_TO_DATE(lastlogin,'%d/%m/%y')
                     end)
    WHERE lastlogin REGEXP('^[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4}$');
```

To me, it is strange that you are setting a character column to a date.

A better approach is to load the data into a staging table, `smart_userstest_staging`.  All the columns are `varchar()`.  There should be no errors loading it in.

Then create `smart_userstest` with logic on each field to convert it to the right value or check that the values are correct (often, you will just copy them in).  This gives you the ability to easily find bad data in the original table and greatly helps with fixing problems.

Modifying the data in place prevents you from having an audit trail of what you had to do to get everything working.  That means that the next time you have to do the task, you have to relearn everything over again.  If you load into a staging table, the logic is all encapsulated in a SQL query that transfers data from the staging table to the real table.

EDIT:

Try this:

```
UPDATE `smart_userstest`
    SET lastlogin = STR_TO_DATE(substring_index(lastlogin, ' ', 1),'%d/%m/%y')
    WHERE lastlogin REGEXP('^[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4}$');
```

This chooses just the `m/d/yyyy` portion of the string.  By the way, I don't see how the string with the hour/minute is passing the `REGEXP` pattern.  I think the problem might be somewhere else.

Comment: I am actually doing this straight on the staging table right now until I get it working - hence "test" in tablename.   Got error "[Err] 1411 - Incorrect datetime value: '1/24/2014' for function str_to_date" on your revised answer.

Comment: @blankip . . . Something is wrong with the value.  It must have other characters in it.  RocketHazmat's solution also should have worked.  You shouldn't be doing updates on the staging table, just queries (which you can put into a temp table if you like).

Comment: Thanks will reload because I am on the row and don't seen any extra characters... much easier if mysql let me pick my format.